# Windows API usage

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I have created a C project in Visual Studio 2005.
Whenever I am using any Windows API(CreateFile,CreateProcess,RegOpenKeyEx,etc),they are not working fine,means resulting in error return value.I am not getting any compile error.
Are they related to project settings,etc

Comment: When you get an error, you have to at least tell what the error is. Also post the code that is giving you the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was using unicode setting,the function name differs for unicode.

Comment: Not if you use the correct typedef. The compiler will automatically insert the correct name for the function (generally by appending either an A or a W to the end of the function's name).

Comment: @Cody: the compiler doesn't do this (I wish it did), the preprocessor does, which can lead to problems here and there.

Comment: @Necrolis: Yes, you're right. I'm not sure how it's relevant; that wasn't really the point of my comment. Relying on the preprocessor *in general* can lead to problems, but I've *never* seen this create a problem. It certainly alleviates more problems than appending the A or W yourself.